# Joining 2 unrelated tables together

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have just delved into PostgreSQL and am currently trying to practice an unorthodox query whereby I want to join 2 unrelated tables, each with the same number of rows, together such that every row carries the combined columns of both tables.

These are what I have:

**technical** table

```
 position | height | technical_id
----------+--------+-------------
 Striker  |   172  |  3
 CAM      |   165  |  4
(2 rows)
```

**footballers** table

```
   name   | age |  country  | game_id
----------+-----+-----------+--------
 Pele     |  77 | Brazil    |  1
 Maradona |  65 | Argentina |  2
(2 rows)
```

What i have tried:

```
SELECT name, '' AS position, null AS height, age, country, game_id, null as technical_id 
from footballers 
UNION 
SELECT '' as name, position, height, null AS age,'' AS country, null as game_id, technical_id 
from technical;
```

**Output:**

```
   name   | position | height | age |  country  | game_id | technical_id
----------+----------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+-------------
          | Striker  |    172 |     |           |         |     3
          | CAM      |    165 |     |           |         |     4
 Maradona |          |        |  65 | Argentina |    2    |
 Pele     |          |        |  77 | Brazil    |    1    |
(4 rows)
```

What I'm looking for (ideally):

```
   name   | position | height | age |  country  | game_id | technical_id
----------+----------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+-------------
 Pele     | Striker  |   172  |  77 | Brazil    |    1    |     3
 Maradona | CAM      |   165  |  65 | Argentina |    2    |     4
(2 rows)
```

Comment: So how do you know the record for `Pele` belongs to the record `CAM`?

Comment: So you can just join them on `id`?

Comment: Sorry, ids in both schemas were meant to be different and unrelated. Updated to reflect the original intent better

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: There is no way you can reliably join those two tables as they don't have anything in common.

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Please explain what makes you combine the Pele row with the Striker row and the Maradona row with the CAM row. Would the other way round (Pele = CAM, Maradonna = Striker) also be a valid result? If not, what is the rule you want applied here for finding the appropriate row?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Seems like they might want to involve a join on row numbers per some sense of order. ("they don't have anything in common" & "There is no way you can reliably join those two tables" are misleading oversimplifications.)

Comment: @philipxy: given the sample data, I don't think those two statements are an oversimplification. You can't define a deterministic sort order on either table to be used with `row_number()` that would bring the rows together as required (in a consistent and reliable way). And I don't see column that could qualify as a "common value" in the sample data either.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For the given data one can sort one table asc by technical_id & the other asc by game_id, each table getting asc row numbers based on that order. Not that I know what the asker wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. But it's not the right way of designing the schema. You should have a foreign key.

```
select t1.position,t1.height,t1.technical_id,t2.name,t2.age,t2.country,t2.game_id
from
(select position,height,technical_id, row_number() over(partition by 
position,height,technical_id) as rnk) t1
inner join 
(select name,age,country,game_id, row_number() over(partition by 
name,age,country,game_id) as rnk) t2
on t1.rnk = t2.rnk;
```

Comment: FKs & other constraints do not need to hold, be known or be declared in order to query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a column to `join` on, so you can generate one.  What works is a sequential number generated by `row_number()`.  So:

```
select *
from (select t.*, row_number() over () as sequm
      from technical t
     ) t join
     (select f.*, row_number() over () as sequm
      from footballers f
     ) f
     using (seqnum);
```

Note:  Postgres has extended the syntax of `row_number()` so it does not require an `order by` clause.  The ordering of the rows is *arbitrary* and might change on different runs of the query.